# Python call another Python script

Tags: python

I use my python script for pentest 
and I want to call another script in a new terminal. 
I'm getting the following error.

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal.

If I use this line with space, it only opens a new terminal with python shell but it doesn't read the path of the new script `/root/Desktop/script/WPA1TKIP.py`:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e python /root/Desktop/script/WPA1TKIP.py")
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/wifite/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When posting code, please indent it by four spaces to make it readable.

Comment: This may help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/there-was-an-error-creating-the-child-process-for-this-terminal/

Comment: Have you though about accepting any answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to quote the command you pass to `-e`:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'python /root/Desktop/script/WPA1TKIP.py'")
```

Otherwise the argument to `-e` is ony `python`, the rest is silently ignored by `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the command you are using is malformed, the command you are running contains a space character, so you need to quote the `python [filename]` part:

```
gnome-terminal -e "python /root/Desktop/script/WPA1TKIP.py"
```

Also, don't use `os.system` use `subprocess`. So you'll use similar commands in the end:

subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', 'python /root/Desktop/script/WPA1TKIP.py'])

Note that in that case, subprocess takes care of the escaping, you just pass a list of parameters/command parts.

Comment: i will tray it ty "subprocess"

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an executable called `python` on your `$PATH`. Are you sure that python is installed, and that `$PATH` includes the appropriate directory?

Comment: It does run Python, but not the file because the filename is passed to gnome-terminal and not python (because of the missing quotes).

Comment: Are you sure it runs python? The error message he quoted is what gnome-terminal prints when the exec fails.

Comment: I tried it, and that's what happened. Also, this is what OP said: `it only opens a new terminal with python shell but it doesn't read the path of the new script`. But maybe that's also another issue, that's just a guess given what is given...

Comment: Right, but then he contradicted himself by saying, "*I'm getting the error "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal"*". Either he got the error, or he got the python shell, but he could not have gotten both from the same call to `os.system()`. Were you able to get the error message that the OP describes?

Comment: And yes, of course, he needs to quote `-e` argument correctly, or he'll just get a python shell.

Comment: No I did not get that message, only the Python shell, and I assumed that was it. So there's something missing here somewhere...